# Clickonce application does not start when .net 4.8 is installed

Tags: c#, clickonce, .net-4.8

Simple things first: I have a .net 4.7.2 clickonce winform application which doesn't start as soon as .net 4.8 (which comes with Windows Updates) is installed. If you uninstall .net 4.8 everything works as expected.
What happens when you click on `.appref.ms` shortcut in the start menu, is that it launches the check for new versions and then it dies. So I checked the eventlog and it revealed this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.GetConfigurationSection(System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.GetAssociatedSection(System.Configuration.ContextInformation, System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.GetAssociatedBindingCollectionElement(System.Configuration.ContextInformation, System.String)
   at System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding.ApplyConfiguration(System.String)
   at xx.xx.xx.xx.WinClient.Initialize.Execute()
   at xx.xx.xx.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper+<>c.<Run>b__0_4(xx.xx.xx.Bootstrapper.IBootstrapperCommand)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ForEach(System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at xx.xx.xx.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.Run()
   at xx.xx.xx.xx.WinClient.Program.Main()
```

This looked familiar as I am indeed using BasicHttpsBinding for a SAP webservice reference. So I wanted to debug the code in order to maybe find more details about why these BasicHttpsBindings are not working when the lastest .net version is installed. 
Unfortunately the application is working properly when it's being debugged. And to make it even worse... when I directly start the .exe file in the `<user>/app` folder it is also working. The only time it is not working is when I start the application with the `.appref-ms` shortcut and - obviously - .net 4.8 is installed.

Is there anyone else who encountered this problem with .net 4.8 and could lead me to the right path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Schadensbergenzer thanks for reporting this.  This sounds like a recent issue which impacts clickonce applications with the October release of a patch for .NET Framework 4.8.  Can you try adding the following to your apps config file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>   
   <runtime>     
       <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Reflection.DoNotForceOrderOfConstructors=true"/>   
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yep that worked. Thanks a lot. Although that's a fix that I'd never come up with a solution like that. I don't even know for sure what this config is doing to my application and why it helps creating `BasicHttpsBindings` ;-). In the meanwhile I found out that MS already reported this as an issue here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4519573/oct-24-2019-kb4519573-cumulative-update-for-net-framework

Comment: @Schadensbergenzer do you mind giving some background on this application?  Are you the developer?  Do you use this application at work, or home, or do you share it with other consumers?  Thanks

Comment: I am the developer and architect, yes. We use this application at work but for internal use only. The use case is some sort of enhanced time tracking. Round about 100 users work with it.

Comment: Found the solution after continuously working for 3 days... I love you man :')

Comment: @jeffschwmsft: It is my understanding, and please correct me if I'm wrong, that it is not possible to install a .NET framework earlier than 4.8 on a PC running Windows 10 Update 1903 with Framework version 4.8 installed on it. What will occur if my application should happen to target 4.7.2 and is deployed using ClickOnce to an internal LAN server to a user's PC running Windows 10 Update 1903 with framework 4.8?  Will the installation fail unless the app is rebuilt for 4.8?